# How can I loop to get the previous value when the currernt value larger than the previous one?

Tags: sql, sap-iq

Source:

```
Seq Amount
1   50
2   48
3   46
4   40
5   45
6   43
7   39
```

Here is what I want,
when the amount in currernt row is larger than the last one, It changes to the previous one.
For example in row 5, the amount 45>40 in row 4, then change it to 40
in row 6, the amount 43>40 in updated row5, then change it to 40

This is the expected result:

```
Seq Amount
1   50
2   48
3   46
4   40
5   40
6   40
7   39
```

I am currently using lag (amount) over (order by seq)
however, the result is not correct. I think I need a loop script but I am not sure how to do that, please help. 
Thanks!

Comment: Seq 6 should be 43, should it not?

Comment: Seq 6 should be 40 since the original amount is 43, which is larger than the updated Seq 5's amount (40)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic version not requiring `LAG`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8087/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Seq] int, [Amount] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Seq], [Amount])
VALUES
    (1, 50),
    (2, 48),
    (3, 46),
    (4, 40),
    (5, 45),
    (6, 43),
    (7, 39)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.Seq, case when t1.Amount < t2.Amount or t2.Amount is null then t1.Amount else t2.Amount end as Value
from Table1 t1
left join Table1 t2 on t2.Seq = t1.Seq - 1
order by t1.Seq
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8087/1/0)**:

```
| Seq | Value |
|-----|-------|
|   1 |    50 |
|   2 |    48 |
|   3 |    46 |
|   4 |    40 |
|   5 |    40 |
|   6 |    43 |
|   7 |    39 |
```

Comment: Thanks your help! But now amount in row 6 > amount in row 5, row 6 should change to 40 instead of 43. i think it cannot just use a simple joining function. is there any other solution?

Comment: Oh, I see. I would look into solutions using CTEs or possibly PARTITION.

Answer (score 0):

Update the column using the logic provided by RedFilter in a while loop until the value of @@rowcount = 0